# Yii2 Сортировка и фильтр связанных таблиц моделей

Tags: yii2

Доброе время суток. Я пытаюсь сделать сортировку и фильтрацию по полю из связанной таблицы.
Структура : 
ClientClient: id, age, first_name, patronymic, last_name.
ClientPhone: client_id, phone_digital.
Проблема заключается в том что не смотря на то что поле поиска у `phone_digital` появилось, оно не работает. Мне необходимо сделать чтобы оно заработало как на поиск так и на сортировку

Model - ClientClient

```
class ClientClient extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public static function tableName(){
    return 'client_client';
}
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['age'], 'integer'],
        [['first_name', 'patronymic', 'last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
public function attributeLabels(){
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'first_name' => 'First Name',
        'patronymic' => 'Patronymic',
        'last_name' => 'Last Name',
        'age' => 'Age',
        'phone_digital' => 'Phone Digital',
    ];
}
public function getclientPhone(){
    return $this->hasOne(clientPhone::class, ['client_id' => 'id']);
}
public function getphone_digital(){
    return $this->hasOne(clientPhone::class, ['phone_digital' => 'id']);
}
}
```

Search Model - ClientSearch

```
class ClientSearch extends Clientclient
{
public $phone_digital;
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['id', 'age'], 'integer'],
        [['first_name', 'phone_digital', 'patronymic', 'last_name'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
public function scenarios(){
    return Model::scenarios();
}
public function search($params){
    $query = Clientclient::find()->joinWith('phone_digital');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        $query->joinWith(['phone_digital']);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'age' => $this->age,
    ]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'first_name', $this->first_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'patronymic', $this->patronymic])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'last_name', $this->last_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'clientPhone.phone_digital', $this->getAttribute('phone_digital')]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ClientSearch extends Clientclient
{
    public $phone_digital;

    ...

    public function search($params)
    {
        ...

        $dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes' => array_merge($dataProvider->getSort()->attributes, [
                'phone_digital' => [
                    'asc' => [ClientPhone::tableName() . '.phone_digital' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => [ClientPhone::tableName() . '.phone_digital' => SORT_DESC]
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        ...

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'LIKE', ClientPhone::tableName() . '.phone_digital', $this->phone_digital
        ]);

       ...
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, я получаю следующую ошибку `Setting unknown property: yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::phone_digital`. Указывающую на `'asc' => [ClientPhone::tableName() . '.phone_digital' => SORT_ASC],`   
         `'desc' => [ClientPhone::tableName() . '.phone_digital' => SORT_DESC]`

Comment: да, sorry, на память писал, исправил

Comment: Сортировка заработала( за что я невероятно благодарен и отмечу ваш ответ верным ). Но к сожалению поиск выдаёт пустой результат.
Есть догадки как исправить?

Comment: сначала исправьте непонятные моменты: во первых у вас странное именование геттеров, принято использовать `lowerCamelCase`, исправьте `getphone_digital()` на `getPhoneDigital()`, `getclientPhone()` на `getClientPhone()`

Comment: во вторых: почему `$this->hasOne(clientPhone::class, ['phone_digital' => 'id']` связь один к одному и почему по полю `phone_digital`? должно быть `$this->hasOne(ClientPhone::class, ['client_id' => 'id']`, т.е. подключая связь в текущем классе вы проговариваете `найди мне связь с ClientPhone у которого client_id равен моему id`

Comment: именно из-за этого `joinWith('phone_digital')` в поисковой модели не отрабатывает как должен, после переименования метода связи нужно будет писать `joinWith('phoneDigital')`

Comment: ну и неясно зачем у вас 2 связи один к одному с одной и той же таблицей

Comment: Огромное спасибо)